# How to sort a "Book" ArrayList without SQL?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

My Book app gathers a collection of `Book` objects using lookups against different `Merchant` objects:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
for (Merchant merchant : merchants)
{
    books.addAll(getBooksForMerchant(merchantName);
}
```

It has to sort the List on the basis of a dropdown box:

```
<select class="sortByDropdown" name="sort">
<option value="lowPrice">Price: Low to High</option>
<option value="highPrice">Price: High to Low</option>
<option value="reviewRank">Avg. Customer Review</option>
</select>
```

Given that a `Book` has a `price` property and a `reviewRank` property, how would I sort the ArrayList of Books in Java before displaying it to the user in the order they requested?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in the same way as you would sort any List. Implement a `Comparator` and call `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Having 3 different ways of sorting means you might need to create 3 implementations, or a single one that you can control to sort 3 ways.

Comment: A single comparator is enough. It's only important to compare the 3 conditions in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the exact same question was asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704804/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-using-multiple-sorting-criteria/3704930#3704930):

Short answer, depending on how flexible your solution needs to be, you could write one Comparator, or write several and compose them together for complex sorting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) is great for this type of thing.  Ordering.compound() allows you to chain the options in exactly the way that you have described.