# How to apply sorting on list of item in android

Tags: android, list, sorting, android-layout, android-listview

I am working on an Android project. I have a list of items, and one row has three columns.
Now I need to sort the list based on these columns.
Column headers are : `number, name, summary` .

Now, if I click on number,than the list should be sorted by number and if I click on name, than the list should be sorted by name.

Now I am not getting which layout, or event I should use for this header in Android.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You have to read this similar question, you will be able to sort your data:

[How to sort an ArrayList using multiple sorting criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704804/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-using-multiple-sorting-criteria)

After sorting data, you have simply to call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

More info about sorting:
http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/Sort-2-attributes-collection.htm

First, create a Comparator class for each
different aspect of the Employee class that you might need.
For example:

```
    public class EmployeeAgeComparator
       implements Comparator 
   {
           public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                int age1 = ((Employee)o1).getAge();
                int age2 = ((Employee)o2).getAge();
                if (age1 < age2) return -1;
                if (age2 < age1) return  1;
                return 0;
           }
     }
```

Once you've got EmployeeIdComparator, EmployeeNameComparator and all the rest, then use this code:

```
       Comparator mc;
       mc = new EmployeeIdComparator();
       Collections.sort(list, mc);
```

Comment: Not sure why you got -1 from somebody. Your answer is good enough: just sort the underlying list and notify observers about the change.

Comment: @Profete162: question is not about how to sort data. question is how to implement in android application. like while developing a web page, we can make table header clickable. but what to do in android. question is for layout.

Comment: Please ask a correct question... Would like to help, but impossible for me to understand what you want! Do you want to explain how to add this code on a Button click?

Answer (score 0):

you can use comparator , in ur adapter of list

```
public class CustomerByNameComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
{ 
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase( o2.getName() );
    }
}
```

hope it help u......