# Custom comparator on multiple fields

Tags: java, comparator

I have a class which is defined as:

```
class Attribute {
    String name;
    Boolean active;
    Boolean obligatory;
    Integer sortIndex;
}
```

I would like to implement a custom sort order in following way:

1. All attributes with name as "Name" should be on the top
2. All attributes with obligatory=true, if two fields are obligatory=true then they should be further sorted on sortIndex.
3. All attributes with active=true but obligatory=false, if two fields are active=true and obligatory=false then they should be further sorted on sortIndex.
4. All remaining attributes should be sorted on sortIndex.

I tried to define a comparator

```
public class AttributeComparator implements Comparator<Attribute> {
    List<Comparator<Attribute>> comparators = Arrays.asList(new NameAttributeComparator(),
        new ObligatoryAttributeComparator(), new ActiveAttributeComparator(), 
        new SortIndexComparator());

    @Override
    public int compare(Attribute o1, Attribute o2) {
        for (Comparator<Attribute> c : comparators) {
            int result = c.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Class definitions for NameAttributeComparator, ObligatoryAttributeComparator, ActiveAttributeComparator are as follows:

```
class NameAttributeComparator implements Comparator<Attribute> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Attribute o1, Attribute o2) {
        int comparisonResult = 0;
        if (o1.getName().equals("Name") && !o2.getName().equals("Name")) {
            comparisonResult = -1;
        } else if (o2.getName().equals("Name") && !o1.getName().equals("Name")) {
            comparisonResult = 1;
        }
        return comparisonResult;
    }
}

public class ObligatoryAttributeComparator implements Comparator<Attribute> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Attribute o1, Attribute o2) {
        int comparisonResult = 0;
        comparisonResult = o2.isObligatory().compareTo(o1.isObligatory());
        if (comparisonResult == 0) {
            comparisonResult = o1.getSortIndex().compareTo(o2.getSortIndex());
        }
        return comparisonResult;
    }
}

class ActiveAttributeComparator implements Comparator<Attribute> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Attribute o1, Attribute o2) {
        int comparisonResult = o2.isActive().compareTo(o1.isActive());
        if (comparisonResult == 0) {
            return o1.getSortIndex().compareTo(o2.getSortIndex());
        }
        return comparisonResult;
    }
}
class SortIndexComparator implements Comparator<Attribute> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Attribute o1, Attribute o2) {
        return o1.getSortIndex().compareTo(o2.getSortIndex());
    }
}
```

With this approach I do not get the expected result. NameAttributeComparator and ObligatoryAttributeComparator are applied correctly but ActiveAttributeComparator is not. My questions:

1. is it possible to implement the desired order with custom comparators?
2. What can be the likely problem in the way this is implemented as above?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

I have followed [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704804/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-using-multiple-sorting-criteria) to come up with the current solution.

The scenario in [Java Comparator for Objects with multiple fields](http://Java%20Comparator%20for%20Objects%20with%20multiple%20fields) is somehow slightly different than this since over here the elements with same value should be further sorted on sortIndex.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with Active comparator? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: With application of ActiveAttributeComparator, the fields  with active=false and obligatory=false come before fields with active=true. The expected result is fields with active=false and obligatory=false should appear below all fields with active=true

Comment: Have you tried Java 8 and `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.thenComparing`?

Comment: @tobias_k: the application I am using has not yet ported to java 8. But java 8 would be a great option here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `ObligatoryAttributeComparator` returns a value != 0 if
`!o1.obligatory && !o2.obligatory && o1.sortIndex != o2.sortIndex`
Therefore `ActiveAttributeComparator` is not consulted at all.