# java sort list by current date then by date comparison

Tags: java, list, date, arraylist, comparator

I have an ArrayList of objects `Foo(int id, Date date)`.

How would i go about sorting this ArrayList to look something like below

```
    id = 3, date = 07 Nov 2016
    id = 2, date = 08 Nov 2016
    id = 5, date = 30 Nov 2016
    id = 1, date = 05 Nov 2016
    id = 4, date = 04 Nov 2016
```

The top three objects are in the future sorted by closest (to the present) first, bottom two are in the past sorted by closest (to the present) first.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's trickier than just sorting by a property.

Comment: And a duplicate of [*How to sort an AreayList using multiple sorting criteria*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3704804).  **Search Stack Overflow** before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by multiple criteria, you need a composite comparator:

```
Collections.sort(dates, (d1, d2) -> {
    if (d1.after(now) && d2.after(now)) {
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
    if (d1.before(now) && d2.before(now)) {
        return -d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
    return -d1.compareTo(d2);
});
```

That is:

- If both dates are after now, sort them in normal order (increasing)
- If both dates are before now, sort them in reverse order (decreasing)
- Otherwise (= one date is before now, the other is after), sort them in reverse order (= newer date comes first, older comes later)

Comment: Thank you its sorting properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sort list by `date`, find the last item with `date` less than `today`, move items from the first to the found item to the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i did not quite understand what you meant.