# Java: Sorting objects in an ArrayList with conditions

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to sort my `ArrayList` alphabetically. Therefore I wrote a `sortEmployees` method. **In case my employees have the same name I'd like to sort them based on their salary, which means that the employee with the higher salary should be printed out first.**

Well, I successfully managed to sort them alphabetically, but **I don't know how I can compare, if employees have the same name and if that is the case, the employee with the higher salary shall be printed.** Thanks.

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public void sortEmployees(){
    Collections.sort(employees, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.compareTo(p2.name));
    for(Employee employee: employees){
        System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: "+employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "Salary: " + employee.grossSalary);
        System.out.println(""); // just an empty line
    }
}
```

Comment: You're almost there. Modify your comparator such that If `compareTo()` is non-zero use this value, otherwise compare the salaries and use that value.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get it. Do you mind showing me that in code?

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.name).thenComparingInt(e -> e.grossSalary)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an appropiate [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will compare two items according to your desired criteria. Then use [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) on your `ArrayList`.

If at a later time you want to sort by different criteria, call `Collections.sort()` again with a different `Comparator`.

Reference: [How to sort an ArrayList using multiple sorting criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704804/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-using-multiple-sorting-criteria)

Just an advice for future questions, please google properly or search on stackoverflow for your problem before asking a new question. Most of the time such trivial questions have already been asked and answered.

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 Did you figure it out or do you want me to edit my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the method equals to return whether two names are equal. You can define your Comparator as follows:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public void sortEmployees(){
  Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override 
    public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
      if (a.name.equals(b.name)) {
        return b.salary - a.salary;
      } else {
        return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
      }
    }
  });
  for(Employee employee: employees){
    System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: "+employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "Salary: " + employee.grossSalary);
    System.out.println(""); // just an empty line
  }
}
```

Comment: While this looks correct, I think it would be better to use a _lambda_, rather than create a `Comparator`. It's less code and fits in with the OP's current implementation.